Trying to find a movie about a computer virus that turns people into ash
The movie focused around a virus or something similar that turns people into black ash/powder. When it happens all you can see is a blurred being screeching. After that happens a man and woman (might be protagonist pair,I am not sure), meet a guy hiding in a room illuminated with red light who explains something like a computer virus came out or something like that. 
This is all what I remember.  This is not a recent one. I saw this way back in 2011 and I want to watch it now. 
